# Knockout: Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I am trying to change an attribute in my model like this `usersProfile.friendRequestStatus() = 'DECLINED';`, but i keep getting the error :

> usersprofilemodel.js:86 Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
>       at Object.success (usersprofilemodel.js:86)
>       at fire (jquery.js:3119)
>       at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:3231)
>       at done (jquery.js:9275)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.callback (jquery.js:9685)

I am a bit confused though, because I feel I am doing everything right. This is my knockout mmdel:

```js
function usersProfileModel(data) {
  var usersProfile = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
  usersProfile.mutualFriendsPercentage = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    if (usersProfile.mutualFriendsCount() > 0) {
      return (usersProfile.mutualFriendsCount() / usersProfile.friendsCount()) * 100;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  });

  usersProfile.addFriend = function() {
    showNotification('top-right', 'info', 'Awaiting response', 250, 2000);
  };

  usersProfile.removeFriend = function(parent) {    
    $.get("http://localhost:8080/dashboard/friendrequest/remove/" + parent.user.userName(), function(data, status) {
      if (data.isSuccessful) {
        usersProfile.friendRequestStatus() = 'DECLINED';
        showNotification('top-right', 'success', 'user has been removed', 250, 2500);
      }
    });
  };
  return usersProfile;
}
```

Can someone please explain what is causing this, I feel I am doing it right.

Comment: You get the error because `friendRequestStatus()` is a function hence you cannot assign a string to it.  I'm not sure what outcome you're expecting from that operation. Did you mean `== 'DECLINED'` instead, in order to compare the value returned from the function? Even then you're missing an `if` statement.

Comment: i am trying to pro-grammatically change the knockout attribute friendRequestStatus()

Comment: It's not an attribute though - it's a function. That's the source of your problem. Unless your code is wrong and it actually is a property, in which case just remove the `()` and it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since friendRequestStatus has been mapped into a KO observable, you should just be able to do:

usersProfile.friendRequestStatus('DECLINED');